# Spacing before and after bulleted list in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I remember seeing an option in Outlook 2013 that allowed me to automatically add space before and after a bulleted list without me having to add a new line break manually, but I can't seem to find this option anymore.

Where do I find this option in Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be a list paragraph style that you have to modify. Here are the instructions to modify (note, I am doing this on Outlook 2010, but the steps should be essentially the same)

1. Compose a new email
2. Create a new list
3. Under the Format Text Tab -> Styles, you should see the List Paragraph Style.
4. Right Click -> Modify...
5. Click Format -> Paragraph
6. Under "Spacing" -> Before/After set to 12pt (if you want a space before and after)
7. Check "Don't add space between paragraphs of the same style"
8. Click OK
9. Select the option button "New documents based on this template" to save the style for next time.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why I had to modify this manually since at the beginning it worked automatically but at least it's solved now :)

Comment: Great to hear! You're welcome!